# Why Symfony 5 controllers must extends AbstractController to make autowiring work?

Tags: symfony, autowired

I tried to make a basic `TestController` with a constructor for autowiring `Logger` service for example. If I don't extends `AbstractController` I get this error :

> The controller for URI "/" is not callable: Controller "App\Controller\TestController" cannot be fetched from the container because it is private. Did you forget to tag the service with "controller.service_arguments"?

Why?

Comment: Include the code for your controller, and your services configuration file (e.g. `services.yaml` or `services.php`).

Comment: Without it it's not a controller. You should create a service or custom class if you dont need the basics of the controller.

Comment: The complete error message has always struck me as a bit strange.  Controller services need to be public because the controller resolver pulls them from the container.  Simply setting the service to public is sufficient to make this message go away.  Tagging the controller service with controller.service_arguments will, as a side effect, make the service public as well.  Hence the error message.  However, not all controllers need that particular tag so the message is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did you forget to tag the service with "controller.service_arguments"?

**Did** you tag your custom controller properly? Usually, that's a sideeffect from extending `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController`: that the tag is added automatically. You can skip extending the `AbstractController`, but then you have to add the tag on your own, and you cannot make use of some helper methods for routing, security checks.

---

Some more details about the problem: the [service to resolve the](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/5.3/Controller/ContainerControllerResolver.php#L48) controller relies on the fact that the controller itself can be fetched as a public service from the container. As nowadays, most services are private per default, this needs to be overriden. Another   [compiler pass](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/5.3/DependencyInjection/RegisterControllerArgumentLocatorsPass.php) takes care of this, and this iterates over all services with the tag `controller.service_arguments`

Comment: The default Symfony configuration used to add the yaml config to tag with `controller.service_arguments`, & ensure that the controller-service was public. Since most controllers are expected to extend AbstractController, this was largely redundant - as explained above. If you don't want to add that tag (or extend the controller) manually mark the controllers as `public: true`